# Refactor an Angular 13 module into a library

Tags: angular, module, refactoring

### ISSUE

I can't get to refactor a part of my app into an angular library as some app skeleton. I have been trying multiple things with lots of different errors each time.

### CONTEXT

I work in a big company and we have a lot of applications to maintain. We have been working on an Angular module with everything to get started (header, navigation, models and services) for any kind of app that we do. Now that the module is ready, I would like to refactor it as a library and deploy it on our artifactory.

### ATTEMPTS

I read the docs about libraries but they're simplistic and don't really cover my needs.
I saw [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473999/converting-an-angular-9-module-into-a-library) too but this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

I tried to generate a new library with the dedicated `ng` command, and put my module in the `/lib` directory. I filled the `public_api.ts` with exports and tried to compile but I don't really understand how to handle depencencies since it doesn't seem to be working: I have no error at build time but can't seem to import the library.

I tried refactoring as a lib directly from my main project directory.
I created a lib folder with the required files.

```
/project
    /lib
        /components
        /directives
        /interceptors
        /models
        /services
    /node_modules
    /theme
        /fonts
    ng-package.json
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    public_api.ts
    my-project.module.ts
    my-project-routing.module.ts
    tsconfig.lib.json
    tsconfig.lib.prod.json
    tsconfig.lib.spec.json
    my-project.component.html
    my-project.component.ts
    my-project.component.scss
    my-project.component.spec.ts
```

I tried building after filling the `public_api` file and the `tsconfig.lib.*` (just extending the main project `tsconfig.json`) but I keep getting build errors such as

```
Error: my-project.component.html:4:1 - error NG8001: '(component)' is not a known element:
1. If '(component)' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If '(component)' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

(component) being the component, but I have this message for everything.

Should I break everything into multiple modules ? Or am going the wrong way here ? A simpler solution must exist, I'm certainly not the first one to try that kind of thing.

The main goal to achieve is to have this base application skeleton, that devs can update with a simple `npm install` rather than pulling a git repository and resolving conflicts.

### EDIT

I tried again from scratch today:

1. I created a new workspace with `ng new my-project --create-application=false`
2. I created a library with `ng generate library my-lib`
3. I refactored what my IDE told me to: added typescript `override` where needed etc.
4. I had some routing module and canActivate guards... Not sure if they could be the issue so I deleted them for now since I had IDE errors with types etc in it (weirdly because I double checked the docs about that)
5. I exported ALL my components/models/services and the module in `public_api.ts`
6. It's worth noting that I have an Abstract Component implementing a Component interface that my components extend, and 2 Abstract Services that my services extend (one or the other)
7. I installed the dependencies, and moved them to `peerDependencies` in `package.json` (I tried to leave them in `dependencies` too)
8. I ran `ng build my-lib`

And now I have this issue that I don't understand

```
λ ng build my-lib
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'my-lib'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

× Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy full compilation mode.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

I also tried to switch to full Ivy compilation mode but I still have that message.

Answer (score 0):

I still have issues that might be related to my lib, but the the build passes and I can import the lib in a project so that pretty much answers the original question.

This is a bit disappointing as I couldn't identify the real cause of the error message but here's what we did:

1. I created a new workspace with `ng new my-project --create-application=false`
2. I created a library with `ng generate library my-lib`
3. I started by adding the interceptors and directives.
4. Instead of copying my `*.module.ts` file I went modifying the one generated by the ng command
5. I added the services
6. I added the components, one by one.

At each addition in steps 3-6 I ran `ng build my-lib` to check, and it eventually passed.

No idea what made it crash.... I committed my files before this last attempt and went comparing afterwards, turns out there was no difference in the end.

So basically, if you encounter a similar issue, you may want to do it little by little or else angular won't be happy.